# Next & Previous (Pagination in this case) Not Appearing

Tags: pagination, query, page-template

I am using a custom page template for my portfolio.  The code is calling the correct number of posts per page but for some reason the pagination links won't show up :-S

My query

```
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 2)); 
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php   
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
    $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
?>
```

The entire markup

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="full_container">
<div id="portfolio_content">
<div id="portfolio_wrap">
<div id="content">

    <?php 
        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 2)); 
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php   
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
    ?>


<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

<span class="img">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-portfolio' ); } ?>

<span class="under">
<!-- Excerpt title -->
<span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>

<!-- Excerpt description -->
<span class="desc">
    <?php my_excerpt('short'); ?>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>


        <?php endwhile; ?>  

<!-- Next/Previous Posts -->
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You should show the code _inside_ `pagination();`...

Comment: Switch to using `query_posts` and your problems will vanish, the pagination functions are designed to work with the main loop, and specifically look to `$wp_query` to determine how many pages there are and whether to page, etc (your pagination function may be doing the same, i'm not familiar with whicever plugin provides that though).. see [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-archive-page-pagination-isnt-working#post-1899689).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="full_container">
<div id="portfolio_content">
<div id="portfolio_wrap">
<div id="content">

    <?php 
        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 2)); 
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php   
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
    ?>


<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

<span class="img">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-portfolio' ); } ?>

<span class="under">
<!-- Excerpt title -->
<span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>

<!-- Excerpt description -->
<span class="desc">
    <?php my_excerpt('short'); ?>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
<?php previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?> / <?php next_posts_link('Next') ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>  

<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This isn't working, sadly.

Comment: wait let me check maybe i did any mistake in typing

Comment: okay find out mistake i post those codes out of loop before which doesn't work

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying.

Comment: previous_posts_link() next_posts_link()

Comment: This codes must be written in loop but i write it out of loop before that's why its not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the variable `$additional_loop` being set anywhere in your code. If you're comfortable with [WP-Pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/), install it and modify your code as follows:

```
<?php
    //You need to handle the 'paged' query var for pagination!
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged'))?get_query_var('paged'):1;
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged)); 
?>
```

Replace the following:

```
<!-- Next/Previous Posts -->
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>
```

With:

```
<?php
    if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
    { 
        wp_pagenavi(); 
    }
    else
    { ?>
        <div class="navigation">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('Previous entries') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next entries') ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php }
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd rather just keep the pagination I have built into my theme right now... suggestion?

Comment: Might have to see how your pagination function works!